# How to stop a sinkTask in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am running a `sinkTask` using `connect-standalone.sh` and connect-standalone.properties. I am doing this in a shell script and I am not sure how to stop the sinkTask once the data is consumed by the consumer.

I tried various settings in the properties file like `connections.max.idle.ms=5000`. But nothing is stopping the sink.

I don't want to try the distributed mode as it requires REST API calls. Any suggest to stop the sinkTask once the messages in the producer are empty?

Comment: 1) What's wrong with REST calls? 2) standalone mode isn't fault tolerant

Answer (score 1):

When running in standalone, the only way to stop a connector is to stop the connect process you started with `connect-standalone.sh`.

If you want to often start and stop connectors, I'd recommend you to reconsider distributed mode as it makes controlling the life cycle of connectors easy to manage via the REST API.